# Conditional Authentication: How to conditionally display login on page servlet

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, authorization

I am running Tomcat 8.  Currently I have pages that users always need login to see, and pages that the user never has to login to see.  I have both of these cases working.

But now I need to make a page that users SOMETIMES have to login to see (based on the data/configuration of what is being asked for).

Given that, I can't just throw the servlet endpoint in the web.xml web-resource-collection, it wont work that way.

I have tried returning a login view from my servlet, with the standard wiring for j_securtiy_check, but when the service comes back it does not look like the login worked.

Comment: what's happening when you forward to login view from your servlet?

Comment: I'm not forwarding to the login view, I'm returning the login view (the url doesn't change).  After the login form is submitted, I get the request back again and there is no user returned from request.getRemoteUser().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get around my issue, here is what I did.

In my servlet, I grab the data for the object I need to render, if the object states the user needs to be authenticated to view, I check the authentication with request.getRemoteUser().

If no user is found, I redirect to a secure url with a new servlet.  The url will have a ?return=myurl in the url.  In this case, the login page displays and the new servlet sees the return url and redirects back to the original page.

The original page now does user lookup again, but this time the user is logged in.

This is not the ideal solution, but it does work.